# Install multiple packages as they existed on CRAN at a specific date?

Tags: r, cran

Suppose someone wrote a script that worked wonderfully 5 years ago, but which doesn't work when packages are installed today (and assume the changes to some packages were very significant).

Is there any way to install CRAN packages by *date*. For example

```
install_CRAN_by_date("2016-05-01", c("rgdal", "sp", "dplyr", "trip"))
```

Is there any simple function that does this?

Comment: there is an option with `versions` i..e `install.versions` where you can specify the package version and if you dpon't know the version, check with `available.versions('rgdal')`

Comment: Thanks @akrun ! Do you know if there's anything written that abstracts away even from version, and just to date? So the user enters a date, and that function (if it exists) works out what version needs installation and runs `install.packages()` with the `versions` argument as per your suggestion?

Comment: For that, the user needs to know the exact date right? and isn't that manual

Comment: You can have `available.versions('dplyr')` and it also returns the 'date' and `version'

Comment: @akrun Basically the user has a script that's 5 years old and doesn't work anymore, but if she could install packages as they were 5 years ago, I think it would work.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks! Is there a simple way to use those e.g. `install_CRAN_by_date("2016-05-01", c("rgdal", "sp", "dplyr", "trip"))` or would there still be a little manual work visiting the snapshots, downloading them, and installing from a local source file? (I know that's not backbreaking work, but I'd be surprised if someone hadn't coded something up already that does that for us)

Comment: Even for that, you need the exact correct 'date' of release.  With `available.versions`, there is a `date` column, which you can match with the input_date and get the corresponding 'version' that can be used in `install.versions`

Comment: @akrun (I will clarify this in the question, because I didn't make it clear enough), but by 'date' I more specifically mean 'the version on CRAN at that date', not the date the package was released (although they could be the same if the date *happens* to be the date of release of a new package version, but that would be purely coincidental)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `checkpoint` package and Microsoft's ["CRAN Time Machine"](https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine) that has daily snapshots of CRAN going back to 2014.

See [this `checkpoint` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/vignettes/checkpoint.html) for examples. Essentially you'd do

```
library(checkpoint)
checkpoint("2015-01-01")
library(your_favorite_cran_package)
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, the UI gives the correct release date ('input_date') of e.g. 'dplyr'.  Get the 'version' based on the `match` between the 'input_date' and the 'version' column from `available.versions` and use that to install with `install.versions`

```
library(versions)
input_date <- "2019-06-29"
dplyr_versions <- available.versions('dplyr')$dplyr
vers <- dplyr_versions[match(input_date, dplyr_versions$version)]$version
install.versions('dplyr', vers)
```

---

With multiple packages, not sure all of them have the same release date or not.  But, if they are, then use a loop with `lapply`